# Create generic Function to filter many Objects that have the same Base Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, inheritance

I'm trying to create a generic Function to pass a filter that I intend to use for many Objects in my project.  All of these objects will have a Base Class called `BaseObject`.

For example:

```
public class Artist : BaseObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //...more properties
}

public class Album : BaseObject
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    //...more properties
}
```

BaseObject has the following:

```
public class BaseObject
{
    public BaseObject()
    {
        Oid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Oid { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime? DateDeleted { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

}
```

I would like to create a Method that could be used for Artist and Album, I have the following, but isn't working, I'm not understanding `<T>`.

```
public static IQueryable<Entities.Core.BaseObject> WhereActive<T>(this IQueryable<Entities.Core.BaseObject> query)
{
    return query.Where<Entities.Core.BaseObject>(b => !b.IsDeleted);
}
```

Above, I tried to replace `Entities.Core.BaseObject` with `T`, but wasn't working.

When I call db.Artist with the `Where` clause:

```
Artist artist = db.Artist
            .WhereActive<Artist>()
            .Where(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Name.Trim()))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

I get an error:

> 'BaseObject' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'BaseObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am sure this is a simple fix, but I am new to LINQ and whatnot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return `IQueryable<T>`, and have a generic constraint on `T` to specify it is a `Entities.Core.BaseObject` (or a class that derives from it)

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereActive<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) 
    where T : Entities.Core.BaseObject
{
    // no need to specify the generic <T> here as well...
    return query.Where(b => !b.IsDeleted);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to constrain the generic parameter to inherit from `BaseObject` and use it as the input and output of your extension method.

```
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereActive<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
        where T: BaseObject
    {
        return query.Where(b => !b.IsDeleted);
    }
```

Comment: Oh, If only I wrote a little less text :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I know .. we were seconds apart :)